# How catch login/logut events for programming a register (logs files) on login/logout in Symfomy 3?

Tags: php, symfony, events, authentication

I'll try to be as descriptive as possible, I'm just a rookie with Symfony.

I am maintaining a report application in symfony, right now I need to create and store in a txt file details of user accesses to the report: names, date, time, ip, time login, time logout.

My problem is that I not have clear how to program during login and logout events. In other words, how can cath the login and logout events?

Following the Symfony documentation, create a very simple login module.

obs. I have only a Bundle: myBundle.

1. Creating firewall in security.yml

   ```
       #This content in Security.yml

       encoders:
       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface: plaintext
       providers:
       our_db_provider:
           entity:
               class: myBundle:myUserClass
               property: username

       firewalls:
       default:
           anonymous: ~
           http_basic: ~
           form_login:
               login_path: /login
               check_path: /login_check
               username_parameter: _username
               password_parameter: _password
           logout:
               path: /logout
               target: /login
   ```
2. Declaring routes in routing.yml

   ```
       //These routes are declared in routing.yml (in the Bundle:myBundle)
       login:
         path:     /login
         defaults: { _controller: myBundle:Security:login }

       login_check:
         path:     /login_check
         defaults: { _controller: myBundle:Security:loginCheck }

       logout:
         path:     /logout
         defaults: { _controller: myBundle:Security:logout }

       access_control:
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

       #This route for redirect to my home page when login succesfull
       my_home_page:
         #Path and controller here
   ```
3. The controllers for routes:

   ```
        class SecurityController extends Controller
        {

         public function loginAction(Request $request)
         {   
             //If the user is login, go in, it's not necesary login again
             if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('my_home_page'); 
             }

             //If code here, logs are write in login and logut indiscriminate

             $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
             $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();        
             $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

             return $this->render('myBundle:Security:login.html.twig', 
             array(
                           'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                           'error'         => $error));
       }

        public function loginCheckAction(){
                //I try code the file logs here for login succesfull
                //But doesn't happen anything
        }

        public function logout(){ 
              //I try code the file logs here for logout
              //But doesn't happen anything
        }
     }
   ```
4. Finally in View

   ```
       {% if error %}
               <!-- This is for personalize the error menssage -->
               <h3>User and/or pass incorrects</h3>
       {% endif %}
       <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post" autocomplete="OFF">

               <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User</label>
               <input type="text" name="_username" id="exampleInputEmail1">

               <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Clave</label>
               <input type="password" name="_password" id="exampleInputPassword1">

           <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="my_home_page">
           <button type="submit">Sing In</button>
       </form>
   ```

I'm try get a solution specifing my own handles, but fails
(This solutions is for Symfony 2, looks deprecated)

You can see: https://gist.github.com/chalasr/69ad35c11e38b8cc717f

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [EventSubscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)s, and specifically [LogoutHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout/LogoutHandlerInterface.html) and [AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.html) like FOSUserBundle does.

[This](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/357/how-to-create-a-custom-logout-event-onlogout-listener-using-fosuserbundle-in-symfony-3) article goes into the specifics of how to use listeners with LogoutHandlerInterface (just ignore the part about using FOSUB as the user manager if you aren't using it).

the `logout()` and `loginCheckAction()` methods are not actually used, they exist to catch the requests for login and logout for the firewall.

Comment: I am really grateful for your contribution, I am guided to implement a solution. I share the solution in detail in the answer to this question, hoping someday it can serve a novice like me.

Answer (score 0):

About solution, efectly it's necessary implement (on symfony 3) [EventSubscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html), in my case the Events:  [LogoutHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout/LogoutHandlerInterface.html) and [DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html). Just like @[Spencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8771552/spencer) says.

Step for solution:

1) Creating *namespace* (one directory) *Listeners* on *MyBundle/Listeners*

2) Creating the Classes *LogoutListener* and *LoginListener* in *Listener* namespace.

- The class *LogoutListener* implements the interface *LogoutHandlerInterface* and rewrite the method logout.
- The class *LoginListener* extends from the class *DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler*. You could implement the interface *AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface* but... seems that you need write a method for management $http (*determineTargetUrl()*), *onAuthenticationSuccess()* must be return a redirect after the login sucessfull

Class *LogoutListener*

```
    //Class for Logout Listener
    <?php
    namespace MyBundle\Listeners;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface;

    class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface {    

        public function __construct(){}

        public function logout(Request $Request, Response $Response, TokenInterface $Token) {
            //Code here that you want that happen when logut sucessfull.
            //In my case, write logs files      
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Class *LoginListener*

```
   //Class LoginListener
   <?php 
    namespace ReportesBundle\Listeners;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\ParameterBagUtils;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    class LoginListener extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

        protected $httpUtils;

        public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils){
            parent::__construct($httpUtils); }

        public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $Request, TokenInterface $Token){
            //Code here that you want that happen when login sucessfull.
            //In my case, write logs files      
            return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($Request, $this->determineTargetUrl($Request));
        }
    }
    ?>
```

3) Declare services in *services.yml*

```
    services:
    #Declaring service for logout event
    mybundle_logoutlistener:
        class: MyBundle\Listeners\LogoutListener

    #Declaring service for authentication success handler
    security.authentication.success.handler:
        class: MyBundle\Listeners\LoginListener 
        arguments:  ["@security.http_utils"]
```

4) Configuring firewall in security.yml

```
 firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check                
                username_parameter: _username
                password_parameter: _password
                success_handler: security.authentication.success.handler           
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
                handlers: [mybundle_logoutlistener]
```

Thanks for help!